# active_alchemy doesn't support some SQLAlchemy parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Does anyone know how I can pass "primary_key" in ActiveAlchemy ?

```
from active_alchemy import ActiveAlchemy
 
class MyModel(db.Model):
    
    name = db.Column(db.String(25))
    is_live = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

# Put at the end of the model module to auto create all models
db.create_all()
```

This works, but the following code doesn't:

```
from active_alchemy import ActiveAlchemy

class MyModel(db.Model):
    
    name = db.Column(db.String(25), primary_key=True)
    is_live = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

# Put at the end of the model module to auto create all models
db.create_all()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? ActiveAlchemy already adds a primary key `id` by default. You can’t have multiple primary keys in one table.

Comment: Previously (when I was using SQLAlchemy instead of ActiveAlchemy as a database), I had 4 primary keys. Also, I don't know how can I get rid of some columns which have already been implemented in "Model" class. Have you ever encountered this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue closed, I implemented my own version of active alchemy. Thanks!